# Finding USB Event Logs for Windows 7

Tags: event-viewer

I am trying to find the Windows Event code for when a USB is inserted into a Windows 7 machine. Also looking for the event code for when a user writes, copies, modifies and deletes a file to/from the USB device.

The Window EventCode 4663 and TaskCategory "Removable Storage" logs are available on Windows 8 and up however, I have not seen any equivalence for Windows 7...

I am primarily looking into generating the logs on my machine so that it can be ingested into my SIEM. I am not looking for any 3rd party tools to use.

Comment: I would ask this on SuperUser. Since it's not programming-related, it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Understood. Thanks David!